# get button state in recycle view

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-recyclerview

I'm using `Recycle view` and I'm trying to set `button` on selected state only once .

```
button 1 : when clicked set is as true .
button2 : when clicked set `button 1` to `false` state and then set `button 2` to `true`
button3: when clicked set `button 2` to `false` state and then set `button 3` to `true`
```

my problem is how to get the previous button view to set it as false ?

```
public class MyCustomAdapterPackages extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCustomAdapterPackages.CustomViewHolderPackages> {


    private ArrayList<Packages> packages;
    private Context mContext;
int id=-1;
    public MyCustomAdapterPackages(Context context, ArrayList<Packages> packages) {
            this.packages = packages;
            this.mContext = context;

    }

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolderPackages onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
             View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.package_row_item, null);
            CustomViewHolderPackages viewHolder = new CustomViewHolderPackages(view);
            return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyCustomAdapterPackages.CustomViewHolderPackages holder, final int position) {

            final Packages pa = packages.get(position);



            holder.PackageButton.setText(pa.getPackageName());
        holder.PackagePrice.setText(String.valueOf(pa.getPackagePrice()));
            holder.PackageButton.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.tab_bg_selector));


        holder.PackageButton.setId(position);
        holder.PackageButton.setTag(id);


            View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {




                        if(id<0){
                            view.setSelected(true);
                            id=view.getId();
                        }
                        else{

                           if(((Button)holder.getTag(id)).isSelected()) {
                               view.findViewById(id).setSelected(false);
                               view.setSelected(true);
                               id=view.getId();
                           }
                            else{
                              id=view.getId();
                               view.setSelected(true);
                           }

                        }


                    }
            };

            //Handle click event on both title and image click
            holder.PackageButton.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
           // holder.PackagePrice.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            holder.PackageButton.setTag(packages.get(position));
         //   holder.PackagePrice.setTag(packages.get(position));
     //   holder.viewGroup.addView(ll);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
            return (null != packages ? packages.size() : 0);
    }

    public class CustomViewHolderPackages extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


            protected Button PackageButton;
            protected TextView PackagePrice;

            public CustomViewHolderPackages(View view) {
                    super(view);
                    this.PackageButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.PackageButton);
                    this.PackagePrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.PackagePrice);

            }

    }
```

}

Log error :

```
Process: hesham.bestdealsoft.topline.elitedishes, PID: 15922
                                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.view.View.isSelected()' on a null object reference
                                                                                         at hesham.bestdealsoft.topline.elitedishes.MyCustomAdapterPackages$1.onClick(MyCustomAdapterPackages.java:75)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848)
                                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20262)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Comment: Could you add id field?

Comment: And where do you set clickListener to button? Post full code of recyclerview

Comment: i have updated the post

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution

i should pass recycle view instance from external class to my custom adapter first

thin inside recycle view-adapter i can get any view by it position in recycle view  and cast it to view-holder and then can do any thing with the holder

here is code:

out side class :

```
        mRecyclerView2 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list_Fragment);
    mRecyclerView2.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView2.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter2 = new MyCustomAdapterPackages(this, PackagesList,mRecyclerView2);
    mRecyclerView2.setAdapter(mAdapter2);
    mAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

in custome adapter class :

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyCustomAdapterPackages.CustomViewHolderPackages holder, final int position) {

            final Packages pa = packages.get(position);



            holder.PackageButton.setText(pa.getPackageName());
        holder.PackagePrice.setText(String.valueOf(pa.getPackagePrice()));
            holder.PackageButton.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.tab_bg_selector));


        holder.PackageButton.setId(position);
        holder.PackageButton.setTag(id);


            View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {



                        if(id<0){ // first time or default 
                            view.setSelected(true);
                            id=view.getId(); 
                        }
                        else{
                            CustomViewHolderPackages row = (CustomViewHolderPackages)mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(id); 

                           if( row.PackageButton.isSelected()) {
                               row.PackageButton.setSelected(false); // previous view 
                               view.setSelected(true); // current view
                               id=view.getId();
                           }
                            else{
                              id=view.getId();
                               view.setSelected(true);
                           }

                        }


                    }
            };

            //Handle click event
            holder.PackageButton.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

    }
```